# Python - Calculating steps in rpg game

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

Problem follows like this:

I use pygame for my rpg game.
I have a player that responds to left, right, up, down and moves in coordinates accordingly (ie. 0,0 -> 1,0 -> 2,0 -> 3,0 -> 2,0)

I'm able to get the counter up every time i press up down left or right as assigned moving buttons.

The problem is that my player can move when holding down ie. left button.
This is registered as "permanent" movement before released.

The counter will go up every time i press the button by 1.
Now I want o to count the movement without needing to count each press since player can move the whole map around without releasing and this is counted as only 1 step.

```
count = 0
    while True:
        for e in pygame.event.get():
            if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_UP:
                player.changespeed(0, -3)
            if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_DOWN:
                player.changespeed(0, 3)
            if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_RIGHT:
                player.changespeed(3, 0)
            if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_LEFT:
                player.changespeed(-3, 0)
            if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_i:
                player_menu = Player_menu()

            if e.type == KEYUP and e.key == K_UP:
                player.changespeed(0, 3)
                count += 1
            if e.type == KEYUP and e.key == K_DOWN:
                player.changespeed(0, -3)
                count += 1
            if e.type == KEYUP and e.key == K_RIGHT:
                player.changespeed(-3, 0)
                count += 1
            if e.type == KEYUP and e.key == K_LEFT:
                player.changespeed(3, 0)
                count += 1
```

How can i define that as long as X changes for player, steps increase in the same rate by 1 and if no changes are done to player, no steps are counted?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question correctly, but if you just want to count how often the player moves, you could increment the `steps` counter when the user presses a key, e.g. `if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT: steps += 1` (in your event loop).

Comment: I'm trying to count the X and Y position change amount regardless of direction. So 1 step = 1 pixel = 0, 0 -> 1, 0 in position.

Comment: then skrx has given a suitable answer - where you implement an increment-counter is your decision, a good idea would be when you perform the change of the x/y-variable of your "character" - whenever you add/subtract one of x or y, increment the counter. I would suggest not doing this on key-input, as there is a chance your character can't move in the desired direction (in front of a wall), hence doesn't take a step => the counter at the key-input would increment by 1 even though x/y position variables didnt change.

Comment: I've tried to implement this but problem is the following now:
When moving event is in a while loop, so when ever player stops moving the values go to 0.
If i run a if statement inside a while loop as soon as i stop the movement if is false and all changes default back to original.
So I'm unable to figure out how to make sure the values keep adding and not default back.
`while True:
for e in pygame.event.get():
 if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_LEFT:
  player.changespeed(-3, 0)`

Comment: Please edit your question and post a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Question edited and clarified.

Comment: Am I right in assuming that you want to measure the distance that the player has travelled? If yes, I'd recommend to use a pygame.math.Vector2 to keep track of the distance and in the main loop just add the absolute values of the x and y velocity of the player to it every frame. I'll post an example if that's what you want.

Comment: I think my assumption was wrong and you really just want to count the steps. In this case I would just check in the main loop if the user is moving (if his x or y speed is != 0) and then increment the counter variable.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever the player's x or y velocity is != 0, the player is moving, so we can increment the `count` variable by 1 each frame in the main loop. (I've increased the speed of the player to 25, so that it's easier to see a single step.)

```
import sys
import pygame as pg


pg.init()
screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))
FONT = pg.font.Font(None, 32)


class Player(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, pos, *groups):
        super().__init__(*groups)
        self.image = pg.Surface((20, 35))
        self.image.fill(pg.Color('sienna1'))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=pos)
        self.vel_x = 0
        self.vel_y = 0

    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += self.vel_x
        self.rect.y += self.vel_y

    def changespeed(self, x, y):
        self.vel_x = x
        self.vel_y = y


def main():
    clock = pg.time.Clock()
    sprite_group = pg.sprite.Group()
    player = Player((300, 300), sprite_group)
    count = 0
    done = False

    while not done:
        for e in pg.event.get():
            if e.type == pg.QUIT:
                done = True
            if e.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                if e.key == pg.K_UP:
                    player.changespeed(0, -25)
                if e.key == pg.K_DOWN:
                    player.changespeed(0, 25)
                if e.key == pg.K_RIGHT:
                    player.changespeed(25, 0)
                if e.key == pg.K_LEFT:
                    player.changespeed(-25, 0)
                if e.key == pg.K_i:
                    player_menu = Player_menu()
            if e.type == pg.KEYUP:
                player.changespeed(0, 0)

        # If the player is moving increment the step count.
        # You also need to check whether the player can move
        # or is blocked by obstacles.
        if player.vel_x != 0 or player.vel_y != 0:
            count += 1
        sprite_group.update()
        screen.fill((85, 81, 66))
        sprite_group.draw(screen)
        txt_surf = FONT.render(
            'Steps: {}'.format(count), True, pg.Color('sienna1'))
        screen.blit(txt_surf, (10, 4))

        pg.display.flip()
        clock.tick(30)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    pg.quit()
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: Thanks you very much, that will work perfectly for my needs.
Found another way of doing it that gives the same result but requires so much more (unnecessary) code and requires global variable (better to avoid), your way is so much cleaner.